# How to pass variable in bash command?

Tags: python, bash, .doc

I am trying to convert multiple .doc files to .docx format using antiword. How to write a command like this:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    subprocess.run("antiword file > file+'.docx'")
```

it shows this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: "antiword file > file+'.docx'": "antiword file > file+'.docx'"
```

There is no other way to read .doc file properly that worked for me other than antiword.

Comment: I have also tried running directly on the terminal using bash loop and it doesn't work either - it just changes the file size to 0 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Subprocess doesn't run bash. So run bash and pass arguments with arguments remembering about proper quoting.

```
subprocess.run(["bash", "-c", "antiword \"$1\" > \"$1\".docx", "_", file])
```

Comment: I am getting files without any data inside - 0 bytes
same as running directly on bash.
But when I do it manually, it works: antiword filename > filename.docx

Comment: What is the output of `type antiword`?

Comment: @thatotherguy antiword is hashed (usr\bin\antiword)